# Expo Error when running Xcode iOS Simulator: No iPhone devices available in Simulator

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, expo

I am trying to run a React-Native project on the xCode iOS Simulator using Expo, and I get the following errors:

**There was a problem booting a device in iOS Simulator. Quit Simulator, and try again.**

Error installing or running app. Error: No iPhone devices available in Simulator.

If I quit the simulator and try again I get these errors:

**iOS Simulator device failed to boot. Try opening Simulator first, then running your app.**

Error installing or running app. Error: Timed out waiting for iOS Simulator device to boot.

I have tried checking there are devices under the hardware tab of the Simulator.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you using Xcode simulator?

Comment: Yes I am. The Xcode Simulator.

Comment: Okay, I am trying again in a new location and something has changed. I get the following messages:

**Downloading the latest version of Expo client app**
**Installing Expo client on iOS simulator**

No error this time, but it's still frozen and the Simulator has not popped up. so I'm wondering if it has to do with my internet speed (84.8 Mbps download, 9.17 Mbps upload).

Comment: Could you try to reinstall you Xcode. How do you start your expo anyway? is it `expo start`?

Comment: I can try reinstalling Xcode. I've used 'npm start', and 'expo start'. I've also tried opening up the Simulator from the terminal.

Comment: Okay, I've reinstalled Xcode and it still gets hung up on **installing Expo client on iOS simulator**. I click around the simulator as it suggests in the Expo docs to get it to ask me permission to install EXPO on the simulator but nothing happens.

Comment: is react-native even usable for development of iOS on MacOS?... literally can't even get the starter app to run, and I've been at it for hours. Most respectable frameworks have you up and running in 30 minutes tops...

Comment: Also: Why downvote this question? There are no good answers to this question anywhere on the internet and it seems like a common enough problem, as it happened to me as soon as I tried to run the starter application.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error message.

I decided to remove and reinstall Expo. While re-installing I noticed that some of the folders use for installation are owned by root and I have some errors while installing. I change the ownership of those folders to my username on my mac. i.e. "sudo chown -R ownerName: /usr/local/lib/node_modules"

I tried to run a new expo project again and got write access issues to a facebook watchman directory, I did the same thing I did above by granting control of this directory to my logged on account instead of the default root which is the owner of the folder at the time of the error.

I tried to run again on ios and everything now works fine

Note: I erase all the content settings in my IOS emulator before running the app on IOS. You can do this by going to the menu on simulator Hardware => Erase All Content and Settings

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was about permissions on folders:

To install Expo on device, just run

```sh
expo client:install:ios
```

But you will get an error saying you have no permission on your user `.expo` folder, so just run with `sudo`:

```sh
sudo expo client:install:ios
```

Now it says `No iPhone devices available in Simulator.`. And of course, running as `sudo` you are not able to find the emulator running on your user. Finally I changed the folder owner to my user: **gustavoeklund is my user, change to your user when running the command.**

```sh
sudo chown -R gustavoeklund: /Users/gustavoeklund/.expo
```

Now I'm able to normally run without `sudo`:

```sh
expo client:install:ios
```